# Bound a double sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the double sum
$$
\sum_{\substack{m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\\ m,n\neq 0} } \frac{1}{(3m^2+(m-n)^2)^k},
$$
where $k$ is a positive integer. I'm interested in bounding this sum, in fact I think it should be possible to show that it is bounded by $1$, and is moreover exponentially decreasing in $k$, but I don't know how to justify this. My intuition tells me that the denominator should behave just like $3^km^{2k}$, so that the sum is $\ll 3^{-k}\zeta(2k)$, but I don't know how to make this more formal.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the double sum diverges when $k=1$, but does converge for $k>1$. I think that $3m^2+(m-n)^2$ takes the value roughly $r^2$ for $N(r)$ pairs $(m,n)$, where $N(r)$ is approximately a constant times $r$ . So something like $\zeta(2k-1)$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616948)

Comment: Indeed that's very similar, one of the main differences is that in the sum I'm interested in we don't allow $n$ or $m$ to be 0, so I think as $k$ goes to infinity, our sum should go to 0

Comment: That difference is not essential. $(\Bbb Z^2)^*=(\Bbb Z^*)^2\sqcup(\{0\}\times\Bbb Z^*)\sqcup(\Bbb Z^*\times\{0\})$, and the two sums over the two last subsets (of these three) are easily expressible in terms of $\zeta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k\ge2$. A natural approach to an upper bound is to use $3m^2+(m-n)^2 \ge \max\{3m^2,(m-n)^2\}$, which is never off by more than a factor of $2$. Ignoring the condition $n\ne0$ and the coefficient $3$, and making the change of variables $j=m-n$, we see that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\\ m,n\neq 0} } \frac{1}{(3m^2+(m-n)^2)^k} &\le \sum_{\substack{m,j\in \mathbb{Z}\\ m\neq 0} } \frac{1}{(m^2+j^2)^k} \\
&\le \sum_{m\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}} \biggl( \sum_{|j|\le m} \frac{1}{(m^2)^k} + \sum_{|j|>m} \frac{1}{(j^2)^k} \biggr) \\
&\le \sum_{m\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}} \biggl( \frac{2m+1}{m^{2k}} + \frac1{(2k-1)m^{2k-1}} \biggr) < 8\zeta(2k-1).
\end{align*}
(A similar approach will show that the sum diverges for $k=1$; indeed the sum over only the terms with $|j|\le m$ already diverges.)

Comment: Oh I see, that's a very good argument. Then, if we don't ignore the 3, we can actually show that the sum is exponentially decreasing, thank you!

Comment: True, or handle the $m=\pm1$ terms separately, since $\zeta(2k-1)-1$ is also exponentially decreasing.